# How to access a model method with javascript

Tags: php, jquery, cakephp

Please have a look at the below CakePHP code

**Flip2.php** (Model)

```
<?php
class Flip2 extends AppModel {
    var $name = 'Flip2';
    public $useTable = false;

        //Increment the correct_answer field of the specific user
        public function correctAnswer($userID=89, $word)
        {
            $setQuery = "UPDATE `users_words` SET `correctanswer` = `correctanswer`+1 WHERE `userid`=$userID && `wordid`='$word' ";
            query($setQuery);

        }


}
```

**Flip2Controller.php** (Controller)

```
<?php
class Flip2Controller extends AppController {

    public function index()
    {
    }       
}
?>
```

**index.ctp** (View)

```
<?php
//echo $this->Html->css(array('bootstrap', 'mark', 'style'));
echo $this->Html->script(array('timer','swfobject','bootstrap.min.js'));
?>
<style>
#hideall {
    display: none;
    opacity: 0.7;
    position: fixed;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    background: #000;
    border: 1px solid #cecece;
    z-index: 1;
    vertical-align:middle;
    text-align:center;
}

.removeCardflip{
    transition: rotateY(0deg);
    -webkit-transition: rotateY(0deg);
    transition-duration: 0s;    
}

/*  SECTIONS  */
.section {
    clear: both;
    padding: 0 10px 0 10px;
    margin: 0px;
}

</style>

<div id="hideall">
    <?php //echo $this->Html->image('progress.gif', array('alt' => 'Wait', 'style' => 'text-align:center; padding-top:200px;'));?>
</div>

<!--<div class="wrapper" style="border: 1px solid red; width: 100%;">-->
    <div class="section group" style="margin-top: 50px;">
        <div class="col span_3_of_3">
            <h3 style="margin:0px; font-size:22px;">Play word game: </h3>
        </div>
    </div>


    <div class="">
        <div>
            <div>
                <span class="remainWords"><?php //echo count($words);?></span> oxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxf <?php //echo $totalWords;?>
            </div>

            <div>
                <?php
                echo $this->Html->image("comic_edit.png",
                                        array(
                                            "alt" => "Pareto List",
                                            "id" => "paretoList",
                                            'url' => "javascript:;"
                                        )
                                    );
                ?>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>




    <div class="container"><div class="row">






<?php



    foreach($worddeck as $worcard)
    {
    ?>
        <div class="xy col-lg-3 col-md-4 col-sm-6 img-rounded" id="card1" style="width:250px; height:200px; background-color:grey; heiht:170px; margin: 10px 10px;">
            <div id="enside1" >
                <h1 data-pos="<?php //echo ; ?>" ><?php echo $worcard['unique_wordsforcards']['en_word']; $enSpell = $worcard['unique_wordsforcards']['en_word']; ?></h1>       
            </div>

            <div id="ptside1" style="display:none;">

            <?php echo $phonemer[$enSpell]; ?>
                <p><?php echo $worcard['unique_wordsforcards']['hint']; ?></p>
            </div>
            <div id="cntrol1">
                <button type="button" id="2" class="a btn btn-success mr5 btn-lg">Acertei</button>
                <button type="button" id="2" class="e btn btn-danger mr5 btn-lg">Errei</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    <?php
    }
?>





    </div></div>


    <!-- jQuery (necessary for Bootstrap's JavaScript plugins) -->
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <!-- Include all compiled plugins (below), or include individual files as needed -->
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){


   $( ".btn-danger" ).click(function(){
        console.log("Red Button");
        var toclose = $(this).parent().parent();
        $.ajax({
          url: "../img/media.jpg",
        }).done(function() {
            console.log( "The act has been done");
            toclose.toggle();
          });
   }); 


   $( ".btn-success" ).click(function(){
        console.log("Red Button");
        var toclose = $(this).parent().parent();
        $.ajax({
          url: "../img/media.jpg",
        }).done(function() {
            console.log( "The act has been done");
            toclose.toggle();
          });
   }); 

  $( ".xy" ).click(function(){

    $(this).find("#enside1").toggle();
    $(this).find("#ptside1").toggle();
    console.log(this);
  });

});


</script>
```

Now, what I need to do is, this. When the user click on the `Acertei` button, I need to execute the function `correctAnswer`. I am very new to PHP and CakePHP so I am really confused about how to do this when a button is clicked. Any advice please?

Comment: @AD7six: Yeah, but I have nothing to do, I have to work with the files I get. Anyways, you know a better way of calling PHP function from View?

Comment: Where are these files coming from if they aren't yours? Please format your questions for readability - the sparse sort-of-formatted code blocks are a chore to read/pick through. See below answer for _a better way_ ®, recognise that what you've asked is borderline off topic because it's so broad (html js and php fixes/changes).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have

```
<div id="cntrol1">
    <button type="button" id="2" class="a btn btn-success mr5 btn-lg">Acertei</button>
    <button type="button" id="2" class="e btn btn-danger mr5 btn-lg">Errei</button>
</div>
```

You should use different IDs for each button.

You can call the `correctAnswer` function with ajax:

Change the button to something like

```
<button type="button" id="2" data-word="<?php $worcard['unique_wordsforcards']['en_word'] ?>" class="a btn btn-success mr5 btn-lg">Acertei</button>
```

And then add the following code in `$(document).ready()`

```
  $(document).ready(function(){
      $(".btn-success").click(function(){
          var word = $(this).data('word');
          $.post('/flip2/correct.json', { word: word })
          .done(function(data) {
              alert('Saved');
          });
```

I am not sure how the user part works. You should probably have that in the session, and not sent to the function. I hardcoded user 89 and added a way for you to send the word.

Comment: Hi, why did you add `<button type="button" id="2" rel="<?php $worcard['unique_wordsforcards']['en_word'] ?>" class="a btn btn-success mr5 btn-lg">Acertei</button>` into the button?

Comment: The `correctAnswer` function needs the word sent as parameter. I assumed you were referring to the word from that foreach, so I added it as rel, to be able to send it in the ajax call

Comment: OK, but actually it was assigned ti `h1` because it get displayed as soon as the page loads. Not when the button is clicked. Yes, `correctAnswer` need to know the word, that is true. Rather than putting it into the button as you did, is there any other way around?

Comment: I don't think there is an easier way

Comment: OK, I did exactly as you mentioned, but it seems like it is not working.

Comment: I made an edit to the ajax call. Can you try that? If it does not work, can you tell me what error you are getting?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/53982/discussion-between-hashmap-and-cornelb).

Comment: That is correct, @AD7six . My answer is just a starting point, something to show the direction. I did not try (make it work) locally. The answer you posted is obviously complete and well explained.

Comment: I changed to `data-word`. And, yes, it should be a post request

Comment: Thanks, I do have a problem. what is this `data-word` ?? Are they HTML commands? I can't find them online.

Comment: check out this page https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/Using_data_attributes

Comment: Thanks. But since the buttons are generated in a loop, it seems like it do not track the data!

Answer (score 1):

### Use an appropriate model method

The function `correctAnswer` in the model would better be written using [updateAll](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/saving-your-data.html#model-updateall-array-fields-array-conditions):

```
public function correctAnswer($userId, $word) {
    return $this->updateAll(
        array('correctanswer' => 'correctanswer + 1'),
        array(
            'userid' => $userId,
            'wordid' => $word
        )
    );
}
```

Written in this way the inputs (`$userId` and `$word`) will be escaped appropriately and not susceptible to sql injection.

### Create a controller action

The doorway to the web for an application is a controller action, create a simple function, calling the model method, and write it to [output json](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/views/json-and-xml-views.html):

```
public function correct() {
    $postData = $this->request->data;
    $word = $this->request->data['word'];
    $userId = $this->Auth->user('id');

    $result = false;
    if ($userId && $word) {
        $result = $this->Flip2->correctAnswer($userId, $word);
    }

    $this->set('_serialize', array('result'));
    $this->set('result', $result);
}
```

Note that

- It'll only work via a post request.
- The Auth component (the session) is used to get the current user id, it's not a user-defined input.
- This function is defined such that it'll work as a json response.
- There's no need to create a view file with the above code.

Be sure to [setup your app to handle json requests](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/views/json-and-xml-views.html#enabling-data-views-in-your-application):

> After adding Router::parseExtensions('json'); to your routes file, CakePHP will automatically switch view classes when a request is done with the .json extension, or the Accept header is application/json.

### Call the controller action

The required js would be of the form:

```
$(".btn-success").click(function(){
    var word = ...;
    $.post(
      '/flip2/correct.json',
      {word: word},
      function (data) {
        console.log(data);
        // {result: bool}
      }
    );
});
```

Note that:

- The url ends in `.json` which is a simple and robust way to provoke CakePHP to respond as json.
- It is a post request.
- The response will be of the form defined by `_serialize`in the controller action.